# I am getting this error while loading "mice" package in RStudio

Tags: r, r-mice

```
library(mice)
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘mice’ in loadNamespace(j
>   <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):  there
>   is no package called ‘lifecycle’

Comment: Install the lifecycle package.

Comment: also helps to remove this installation of mice.. there might be some clash

Comment: is there a dupe for this? Should there be a canonical dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+%22there+is+no+package%22

Comment: getting these errors while installing lifecycle
installing source package 'lifecycle' ...

Error: unexpected symbol in "tools:::makeLazyLoading("lifecycle", "C:/Users/shihab's pc/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/00LOCK-lifecycle/00new", keep.source = FALSE, keep.parse.data = FALSE, set.install.dir = 'C:/Users/shihab"
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'lifecycle'
removing 'C:/Users/shihab's pc/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/lifecycle'

Comment: Using windows explorer, delete the folder "00LOCK-lifecycle" and try installing it again.